# How can you replace an item of list on python by index

Tags: python, list, encryption, indexing

For whatever reason (I should be  using JS), I am using Python to create an encryption/decryption program. In the encryption program, spaces are carrots (^). In the decryption program I have:

```
msg = raw_input("Msg: ")
dmsg = list(msg)
for i in dmsg:
    if i == "^":
        dmsg[i] = " "
print dmsg
```

When given the string "^^^", the output is... "TypeError: list indices must be integers, not Unicode". All I'm looking for is a function or statement.

Comment: I am on windows 10 and I am using IDLE

Comment: Windows 10 supports IDLE just fine.

Comment: `i` is not the index of `dmsg`

Comment: Think about what exactly your iterating over in your for loop. You error should then become clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are iterating over the list element, but later you are using the element as an index where you need an integer instead. 
seems like what you want should be as below

```
msg = raw_input("Msg: ")
dmsg = list(msg)
for i in range(len(dmsg)):
    if msg[i] == "^":
        dmsg[i] = " "
print dmsg
```

OR

```
msg = raw_input("Msg: ")
dmsg = list(msg)
for n,i in enumerate(dmsg):
    if i == "^":
        dmsg[n] = " "
print dmsg
```

better way can just use `str.replace` method

```
msg = raw_input("Msg: ")
dmsg = msg.replace('^', ' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in dmsg:
```

this code is iteration all the elements in the list, not index.

try to use replace for string. no need to convert to list

```
msg = raw_input("Msg: ")
dmsg = msg.replace('^',' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

Focusing on error you are getting,

You can using character for list indexing, if you need to mutate string you should use [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=enumerate#enumerate),

```
In [18]: msg = raw_input("Msg: ")
    ...: dmsg = list(msg)
    ...: for index, ch in enumerate(dmsg):
    ...:     if ch == "^":
    ...:         dmsg[index] = " "
    ...: print dmsg
    ...: 
Msg: My Message^faf
['M', 'y', ' ', 'M', 'e', 's', 's', 'a', 'g', 'e', ' ', 'f', 'a', 'f']
```

Answer (score 0):

please do like this

```
for i in range(len(dmsg)):
    if i == "^":
        dmsg[i] = " "
```

Comment: Although this may answer the question, some comments and/or explanation as to how and why this works would be nice. That will help other users as well.